# Serialize an object which has a json-format-string to json

Tags: java, gson

I have an object like:

```
public class Foo{
  public String f1="[{\"jsonField\":\"something\"},{\"jsonField\":\"something\"}]";
}
```

Gson would serialize it to:

```
{"f1":"[{\"jsonField\":\"something\"},{\"jsonField\":\"something\"}]"}
```

The f1 field was serialized to a string. Apparently, the field is a well formed json-format string. How can I do to serialized the field to an jso array, like below:

```
{"f1":[{"jsonField":"something"},{"jsonField":"something"}]}
```

PS. For performance consideration, I can't deserialize then serialize the field.

Comment: If you're using Jackson, you can use the `@JsonRawValue` annotation on the field (removed as an answer as you're using Gson, but just in case).

Comment: Thanks for @nullPainter! This is exactly I want! The annotation works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Gson is serializing your string field to a string. That's normal. If your field, however, was a `List<String>`, Gson would give you:

```
{"f1":["jsonField:something","jsonField:something"]}
```

And if it was a List where something has a field called `jsonField` you'd get what you actually want.

This is the implicit way that Gson serializes your objects. If you don't like it, you need to implement your own `TypeAdapter` and register it with Gson at the builder.

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
builder.registerTypeAdapter(MyObject.class, new SomethingGsonAdapter());
Gson gson = builder.create()
```

And you need to define:

```
public class SomethingGsonAdapter implements JsonDeserializer<DataItem>, JsonSerializer<DataItem>;
```